# Ideas for read csv, run function and write result

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a .csv file with 300k+ zip codes, I need to obtain the latitude and longitude of every single zip code. The idea is to, for every cell I run the function below that returns the lat. and long. of the zip code, but I don't know how i can get the lat/long and store with the zip code.

The csv is a one column table with all the zipcodes,

| zipcode |
| --- |
| 198199 |

I'm looking for ideas...

Thanks in advance

```
import pycep_correios
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

zipcode = ''

adress = pycep_correios.get_address_from_cep(zipcode)

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="test")
location = geolocator.geocode(adress['logradouro'] + ", " + adress['cidade'] + " - " + 
adress['bairro'])

print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pgeocode` library and install it using `pip`

```
pip install pgeocode
```

Create an object: `location_code = pgeocode.Nominatim()`

You can pass along a specific country code if the zip codes are all in a certain country.

And finally ask for a query `addr = location_code.query_postal_code(75013)`

it will give you the information about the zip code:

```
print(addr)

output:

postal_code                 75013
country_code                   FR
place_name        Paris 13, Paris
state_name          Île-de-France
state_code                     11
county_name                 Paris
county_code                    75
community_name              Paris
community_code                751
latitude                  48.8322
longitude                 2.35245
accuracy                        5
```

You can get the longitude and latitude as follows:

```
addr.latitude

output: 48.8322


addr.longtitude

output: 2.35245
```